# phpmyadmin I am trying to create a "category" table on my localhost server using PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

Query that I have used is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `category_status`) VALUES
(1, 'Flu & Cold', '1'),
(2, 'Vitamins & Supplements', '1'),
(3, 'Chickenpox', '0');
```

This query executes successfully initially but when I tend to browse the  table,
this error shows up

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` ( `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUT...' at line 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22nI.png)
I am using xampp 8.1.4-1.

But I  can view the structure of the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ9nU.png)

Comment: This is a wild guess, cause I am not using MariaDB. but the error tells you about creating a table if not exist..  but you don't have that kind of code in your post.. 
did you try to run this code multiple times?  Cause if indeed the table exist the you are going to get an error. but having it as the error implies might change things. 
Give it a try 
What I mean here is change the Create table to create table if not exist ...

Comment: Are you still getting the SAME errors after your edit from 7 mins ago ?  (If not, then this would be a great time to delete the question, because it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Yes. @Luuk. Same error.

Comment: Just do the `DROP TABLE...` then check if your table is really gone. Then next step create it, and check if it's empty, ...

Comment: DROP TABLE works. The table gets deleted. And then I created the table again but the same error occurs. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category ( category_id int(11) NOT NULL AUT...' at line 2 .

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce with MariaDB 10.5.12, and I do not seen anything version specific.  Can you tell the output of `SELECT version();` ?

Comment: 'but when I tend to browse the table, this error shows up' - perhaps you are not browsing but creating. Can you create and execute a simple sql script eg select * from <tablename> and describe how you are trying to browse.

Comment: Note [CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE category ....](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) removes the need to `DROP TABLE IF EXIST`. Your syntax error look like a) a missing `;` at the end of `DROP TABLE` despite the text quoted, or b) using a client interface that is expecting a single command (maybe or using a different delimiter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM category
```

shows all the rows of the category table.
I figured this is not an error.[Even though I cannot access the category table inside the PHPMYADMIN. ]

Thanks.
Any suggestions are welcomed.